# Arabic alphabets in output..?

Tags: language-support

Why there are Arabic Alphabets instead of English in this output? It happens whenever the output is about some system files, but why not English?

[image: terminal output]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the output of the `locale` command`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your Regional Formats setting is an Arabic locale. [Look here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html) about how to change it.

Comment: It would be preferable if you could include the most important key points of that external link into your answer.

Comment: @ByteCommander: I don't understand how you can consider a link to the official Ubuntu documentation to be *external*.

Comment: It is *external* to AskUbuntu.com and we generally do not want link-only answers that become pretty useless if you strip the link away. Links should always be an *additional source for more information* or a reference to where you got your information from, not the only information. It does not really matter for this whether the link points to official documentation or not (although official docs are of course better than random blogs or articles).

Comment: @ByteCommander: The question is a duplicate in nature anyway, so I just vote so.